# How to block cd/dvd drive in Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, dvd, cd, restricted-access

I have created 3 standard users in my system and I want to disable CD/DVD drive for them.

How to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove them from the `cdrom` group (as well as `admin`/`adm`/`sudo`) to restrict the privileges:

```
deluser username groupname
```

e.g.

```
deluser gert cdrom
```

Then log out and log back in to make it effective.

*Note! Make sure to use the second argument to `deluser`, otherwise it will delete the user.*

Comment: +10 for the warning note ;)

Comment: i will test that and reply back